# refer bean defined in another .xml

Tags: java, spring

I have 2 spring application context XMLs:

A.xml

```
<bean id="aBean" class="...">
    <constructor-arg name="..." ref="..."/>
    <constructor-arg name="bBean" value="#{getObject('bBean')}"/>
</bean>
```

B.xml

```
 <bean id="bBean" class="...">
    ...
 </bean>

<import resource="classpath*:A.xml" />
```

The file A.xml is not under my control, so I can't import B.xml with `<import resource="classpath*:B.xml" />`, but B.xml imports A.xml, so it's all the other way around.

The aBean is consistently instantiated with the bBean as null, due to the permissive `SpEL` syntax `#{getObject('bBean')}`.

Is there a way to overcome this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

**Main class**:

```
package com.example;

import com.example.route.A;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;


@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource(locations = {"classpath*:/ctxt/B.xml"})
public class DemoApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctxt = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

        A a = ctxt.getBean(A.class);
        System.out.println(a.toString());   // A{b=com.example.route.B@5488b5c5}   <-- A init correctly with non-null B


    }
}
```

**Class A**:

```
package com.example.route;

public class A {

    private B b;

    public A(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("A{");
        sb.append("b=").append(b);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**Class B**:

```
package com.example.route;

public class B {
}
```

**/resources/ctxt/A.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="aBean" class="com.example.route.A">
        <constructor-arg name="bBean" value="#getObject('bBean')"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**/resources/ctxt/B.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="bBean" class="com.example.route.B"></bean>

    <import resource="classpath*:ctxt/A.xml"></import>
</beans>
```

Comment: This project works correctly. However, I ended up having another file A.xml where I defined the bBean, so that the 2 files called A.xml found in classpath are merged in one. In my project is not working, probably due to a weird way of loading xml of the whole dependency tree, that includes ~100 modules.

Comment: if it's not working on your big project check your classpath. if you are creating a big jar, open it up and see where is that xml file, it's probable that you are not correctly referring to it in your "classpath*:" string literal definition.

Comment: Classpath should be ok, since A.xml is at the root level of A.jar, included in B as a second level dependency like this: B->(other module)->A. Using intellij idea spring plugin and clicking on `<import resource="classpath*:A.xml" />` correctly resolves to that file.